# Django - Object with many categories and many subcategories

Tags: django, django-models, categories

I have been struggling with a model for this.
Im developing a directory of companies in the music industry. We already have data base of 500 companies. We have this categories: Audio, Video, Ilumination, Stages, Music Intruments, Talent, Schools and Dj.

This categories have this subcategories.
- Audio: recording, installation, rent, retail
- Video: installation, rent, retail
- Ilumination: installation, rent, retail
- Stages: Bars, Discos, theaters, stadiums
- Music Intruments: retail, rent
- Talent: manager, record label, booking
- Schools: audio, production, theater, dance
- Dj: booking, retail

Many companies enter in many of this categories, and inside this categories they enter in many subcategories.

Example: 
Company X sells video and audio products but the also offer the installation service for the audio products.
So Company X
- Audio: Retail, Installation.
- Video: Retail

In your opinion how can i manage to design the models????

Thanks in Advance.

This is my code by far, but its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The following method is just a simple way of solving the problem, it may not be the most efficient way of doing it but it solves the issue as a whole.

models.py

```
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sub_categories = models.ManyToManyField(SubCategory, blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, blank=True, default=None)
    sub_categories = models.ManyToManyField(SubCategory, blank=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```